# Is there a grep switch that reads a file for filter terms?

Tags: text-processing, grep

Assuming file a.txt has:

```
1a
2b
3c
4d
```

so

```
grep "1" a.txt
```

would return:

```
1a
```

and

```
grep "3" a.txt
```

would return:

```
3c
```

what if i want to put a criteria file named crit.txt with the following content:

```
1
3
```

is there a switch in grep say -cf for criteria file where i could do

```
grep -cf crit.txt a.txt
```

that would return:

```
1a
3c
```

or is there other tool that does the same thing, and provide me with an example on how to use the tool.
The tool should be a one liner command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`man grep`:

```
-f FILE, --file=FILE
          Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line. The empty file contains zero patterns, and therefore matches nothing.  (-f is specified by POSIX.)
```

Comment: you're the man!!